# ¿Cuál sería la expresión regular de un número con decimales?

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito una expresión regular que evalúe si el número contiene un punto decimal, y si es así que tenga más dígitos a la derecha. Ejemplo:

```
10     --> Válido
10.    --> No válido
10.2   --> Válido
10.2.  --> No válido
10.2.3 --> No válido
```

Comment: ¿Podría darse el caso en el que recibieras como entrada un número decimal en notación científica? Mera curiosidad

Answer (score 2):

Esta es la expresión regular que necesitas.

```
^(\d+)?([.]?\d{0,1})?$
```

Puedes personalizar a medida usando esta [herramienta online](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Pero esta expresión limita el número a un solo decimal y no tiene en cuenta números decimales negativos :(, ¿no sería mejor 
la expresión "^-?(\d+)?([.]?\d+)?$" ?

Comment: Falla en estos casos por encontrar cuando no debería: `string vacío`, `10.` `.1`. También, falla al no encontrar `10.10`, aunque ahí no queda claro por el enunciado si se debería admitir más de 1 decimal, aunque parece que sí.

Answer (score 2):

Del sitio en ingles:
fuente:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053605/regex-to-allow-only-a-single-dot-in-a-textbox

```js
let numero1 = "10.";
let numero2 = "10.5";
console.log(numero1.match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/));
console.log(numero2.match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/));
```

Answer (score 0):

está son las pruebas que realizé en la consola del navegador, espero te sean de ayuda.

```
var regex = /(^\d+.\d+$)|(^\d+$)/g; 
regex.test('12.32');
```

saludos!